# what is a function with the following type signature: (x) => (func) => (...values) => func(x,...values)

Tags: javascript, lisp, functor, lispyscript

I have a function which I've written for passing context around in for node js written using lispyscript, it does what I want. The actual implementation of this function is not an issue, this is a vocabulary question.

Does a function with this type signature have a name?

*edit:*
I am pretty sure one would call this a type of functor, if that is correct, what type of functor would it be?

```
(defun closeOverDir (dir)
  (defun closure (fn)
     (lambda () (fn dir ...arguments))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see any relation to the mathematical structure of a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). Being a function that closes over (part of) its (lexical) scope (and thus, a "closure") it's obvious that it is a [function object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object), which are also commonly (at least for the C++ community) called "functors".

Looking at the signature

```
(x) => (func) => (...values) => func(x, ...values)
```

if one swaps the first two arguments, then the signature

```
(func) => (x) => (...values) => func(x, ...values)
```

is basically the same as for [partial application](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Partial_function_application#Common_Lisp): Supplying a function `func` as well as some parameter value(s) `x` gives a function, that expects more parameter values (the rest) and will apply the function `func` to the parameter value(s) given to the partial application `x` as well as the parameter values given to the result.